# Why is this recursive and causing an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, recursion

I'm extending Backbone.View to support subviews and I have a `addSubview` method that just adds a Backbone view to a hash. Easy enough. I'm now attempting to make it so whenever you `destroy` a view it destroys all the subviews. I thought this would be easy enough as well, but my method is going in an infinite loop:

```
destroy: function () {
  debugger;
  // Call destroy on all subviews. If the subviews have subviews they'll
  // be destroyed as well
  for (var v in this._subviews) {
    this._subviews[v].destroy();
  }

  // Instead of calling `delete` on every view we wipe everything out after
  // we're done destroying all the views
  this._subviews = {};

  // Finally, since all the subviews are destroyed it's safe to destroy
  // this view
  this.remove();
},
```

What happens is, that debugger is called the first time and `this` is the view `destroy` is called in (right), 2nd time it's called on the first subview (right), third - ∞ it still keeps calling the first subview. Playing through it step by step it:

1. Hits the debugger
2. Gets to the `this._subviews[v].destroy();` line and `v` == 1st subview
3. Jumps back to the top debugger.

That's all. And it repeats forever. Any ideas or advice?

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iyApuga/1/edit

Comment: Can you create a fiddle by any chance?

Comment: @thefourtheye here you go: http://jsbin.com/iyApuga/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening here is that the `object` called `_subviews` is being stored on `Foo.View`'s prototype (Backbone's `extend` method is doing this) and is thus being shared by *all* instances of `Foo.View`. Here's where that's setup:

```
Foo.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    _subviews: {},  // right here
```

This causes a problem because when you add your first subview, it is added to `this._subviews`. Because the `_subviews` object is being shared by every instance of `View`, when you add a subview to a subview, all other views think that `View` is a subview of themselves.

Specifically, what's happening here is that when you call `.destroy()`, at the top in your loop that calls `destroy()` on all subviews accidentally calls `destroy()` on the same exact View again. The `_subviews` variable doesn't get cleared out until several lines after the loop:

```
// Instead of calling `delete` on every view we wipe everything out after
// we're done destroying all the views
this._subviews = {};
```

Because of this, it becomes infinite because it is iterating over the same list of `_subviews` over and over, getting stuck on the first one which never quite seems to get removed.

To make the world happy, the `_subviews` object should be an instance variable per-`View` and not on the `View` prototype. To do this you should assign a fresh one on every new `View`:

```
  initialize: function () {
    this._subviews = {};
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `_subviews` is **being shared** between the parent `Foo` **and** the child `Foo` instances. The fix is to initialize `_subviews` for each instance:

```
initialize: function () {
    this._subviews = {};
}
```

It's a very common gotcha when trying to use Javascript in a *class-oriented* style.